# Which parts of speech are 'cause'?

Tags: meaning, parts-of-speech

In this question:

> What problems will this *cause* for individuals and society?

Which parts of speech are **cause** in this question?
If it is a noun, why isn't there **be** before ***this cause***?
If it is an adjective, what is the role of **this** ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'Cause' in the sentence given is neither noun nor adjective, it's verb.

To understand this try answering your question - This will **cause** the problems like .... to the individuals and to the society.

cause (noun) - the reason behind some action.

Examle: The cause of our country's plight is corruption.

Or as you asked use of **be** look at this:

Corruption **is** the cause of our country's plight.

to cause (verb) - to make something happen. 
Lack of exercise causes ill health.

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/cause